# Virtual buttons are not visible in android 4.0 emulater

Tags: android

Does android-sdk 4.0 platform supports virtual buttons(like: back button, home button etc). I installed android 4.0 in my eclipse and created AVD with respect to 4.0. but virtual buttons are not visible in my emulator.? How to show these virtual buttons in emulator.

Thanks

Comment: Yes. I got solved my problem. Android 4.0 platform supports virtual buttons. These buttons are visible in my emulator. while creating AVd select Built-in radio button in the drop down choose WSVGA option. this is for large size emulator select and create AVD.
Thanks

Comment: If you get the latest tools and Android 4.0 SDK updates, you have the ability to toggle on/off whether or not the emulator emulates a device with a physical MENU button or not.

Answer (score 0):

Just be sure to have the following property inside $HOME/.android/avd/YOURS.avd/config.ini:
`hw.mainKeys=no`